# JQuery not sliding folder

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a iPhone looking folder menu bar. When i click each item (info tab_(number), it should open the appropriate "infotab_(number)_s" div. _s standing for "show". When one is open and the user click another item on the menu bar, it should close and open the one they clicked. My script doesn't open them, maybe I wrote something wrong.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7FkqH/

So basically if I click the first li with id of infotab_one, It should slide down, info tab_one_s. If I click info tab_two, it should close infotab_one_s and open infotab_two_s.

If that doesn't make sense I will clarify if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7FkqH/7/), i think this is what you intended.

`$('.infotab:visible').slideUp('fast');`

In the code above you had sideDown and a callback function. The first time you click on a `#nav_login_navigation li` there's no visible `.infotab`'s hence  `$('.infotab:visible').slideDown('fast', function() {` will not run because no visible divs with class `.infotab` were found. Since you want previous visible divs to disappear you want `slideUp` instead and not `slideDown`.

Comment: Yes basically! Now I'd like to improve it some. I will make another fiddle